# Permission to access index.php in subfolders

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website that is written in four different languages (written in PHP). For every page I need to go through an index.php file. Is it allowed to have an index.php file inside every language folder? 
How can I configure it in the .htaccess file? Because when I put it online I get an error saying

```
You don't have permission to access /de/index.php on this server.
```

There is also an index.php file in the root

Thanks for your help !

Comment: what do you mean by "Is it allowed to..."?

Comment: @Hallur Is it correct to have a structure as followed: 
/index.php, /de/index.php, /it/index.php, /fr/index.php

And how can i configure htaccess to have avoid the error?

Comment: It really depends on the structure of your site and how it is programmed. Some programmers design their program in a way that only 1 copy of the site handles all the languages, some design in a way that you need 4 copies of at least some of your files for each language(which is not recommended)